# bootstrap-select shown event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using bootstrap select for my select box. I want to do some action once the drop down opened. I used the following code but shown event not getting fired. I tried with changed event also. Nothing worked for me. Some one suggest a way to do this.

JS

```
$(function(){
   $('#c_select #hc_id').selectpicker();

   $('#c_select .selectpicker').on('shown.bs.select', function (e) {
    alert('dd');
   });

   $('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
    console.log('ddddddddddd');
   });

})

<div id="c_select">
  <select id="hc_id" name="hc_id" data-focus-off="true" class="selectpicker change-cc" data-container="body" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="0" data-content="<span class='select-label first'>Select </span>"></option>
    <option value="1" data-content="<span class='select-label first'>AAAAAAAAAAA</span>"></option>
    <option value="2" data-content="<span class='select-label first'>BBBBB</span>"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(function(){
   var select = $('#c_select #hc_id').selectpicker();

   select.on('shown.bs.select', function (e) {
    alert('shown');
   });

   select.on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
    alert('changed');
   });
})
```

```html
<div id="c_select">
 <select id="hc_id" name="hc_id" data-focus-off="true" class="selectpicker change-cc" data-container="body" data-live-search="true">
   <option value="0" data-content="<span class='select-label first'>Select </span>"></option>
   <option value="1" data-content="<span class='select-label first'>AAAAAAAAAAA</span>"></option>
   <option value="3" data-content="<span class='select-label first'>BBBBB</span>"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is an example  https://jsfiddle.net/caliberdev/8pc374xf/

Comment: by first time click you mean, when you initially click on dropdown? or when you click on item inside dropdown? Also check what version you are on (bootstrap-select) and check if it is fully compatible with bootstrap + jquery.

Comment: when you initially click on dropdown

Comment: check out my example, it works when i initially click on the dropdown and click on an item too. Make sure you are using correct version of bootstrap-select/bootstrap/jQuery. also your options markup in example was incorrect, maybe that was causing issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try Doing your action on focus

```
 $('#c_select .selectpicker').on('focus', function (e) {
    alert('dd');
   });
```